# Why csv writer slows down as csv size grows

Tags: python, multithreading, csv

I am writing a script that reads multiple files from a folder “ExtendedReport” and writes each file as a dictionary to one csv file using DictWriter. The program does it in multiple threads. The folder contains 11 million files in sav format, size of folder 180Gb.

The question is why the program starts writing the csv very fast and as file size grows it slows down? And what I can do to save fast speed.

```
#%%
os.chdir('ExtendedReport')
fnames = glob.glob('*sav')   #list of filenames in a folder
os.chdir('../..')

def worker(q, csv_writer_lock, writer):
    while True:
        filename = q.get()
        if filename is None:
            break

        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            json_text = pickle.load(f)

        with csv_writer_lock:
            if isinstance(json_text['Data']['Report'], dict):
                writer.writerow(json_text['Data']['Report'])
            elif isinstance(json_text['Data']['Report'], list):
                for report in json_text['Data']['Report']:
                    writer.writerow(report)



#%%
start = time.time()
csv_writer_lock = threading.Lock()
os.chdir('output')
with open('fulldb_ExtendedReport.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    os.chdir('ExtendedReport')
    fieldnames = list(added_dict['Report'].keys())
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()

    threads = []
    queue_size = 6
    num_threads = 4

    q = Queue(queue_size)
    for i in range(num_threads):
        th = Thread(target = worker, args = (q, csv_writer_lock, writer))
        threads.append(th)

    for i in range(num_threads):
        threads[i].start()

    for i in range(len(fnames)):
        q.put(fnames[i])

    for i in range(num_threads):
        q.put(None)

    for i in range(num_threads):
        threads[i].join()

    os.chdir('..')
print("Writing complete")
os.chdir('..')
end = time.time()
```

**UPD**
I made an update to a code to measure average time of executing worker and added `time_list = []` for saving measures:

```
def worker(q, csv_writer_lock, writer):
    while True:
        start = time.time()
        filename = q.get()
        if filename is None:
            break

        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            json_text = pickle.load(f)

        with csv_writer_lock:
            if isinstance(json_text['Data']['Report'], dict):
                writer.writerow(json_text['Data']['Report'])
            elif isinstance(json_text['Data']['Report'], list):
                for report in json_text['Data']['Report']:
                    writer.writerow(report)

        time_list.append(time.time() - start)
```

I checked 200, 2000, 20000, 50000, 100000 files to write. Every time the time was about 0.002 sec. However evidently now it is way slower after at least 1 million files.

Comment: `fnames` is undefined in your code. In the worker you never close the `filename` you opened, so it might be using up system resources.

Comment: @martineau I edited post to specify fnames. This is just a list of filenames in a folder. Also, thank you, i added a context manager to close file in worker. However this actually just postponed the problem. If previously csv write slowed down at csv reaching size ~300Mb, now it slows down at ~600Mb.

Comment: Have you done any benchmarking and/or profiling? We can’t help with that or improving performance without the ability to run the program.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I think the issue is solved. I reloaded spyder. After that the speed stopped to slow down with the code above. Maybe python process somehow left files, not closed before martineau comment, open in a memory, I don't know.

Comment: @Gimbo Great! It's unrelated to the problem, but have you considered using something like a ThreadPoolExecutor? Those for loops are just begging to be simplified. Also, is having all the threads writing to the same file not an issue? I hadn't noticed that when I first read the code.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I started to use concurrent programming just two days ago. I saw ThreadPoolExecutor, however at first glance didn't get the logic of the object, so selected the queue as more clear way to make program. However if you suggest some articles to examine the topic, I'll appreciate that. About the threads - actually, as you can read in the UPD of question, the writer speed is ok at the beginning, so it shouldn't be the problem with Lock or threads. I think maybe the problem is with file handle of big file or I have something overloading my process.

Comment: Since there are 11 million files, your code creates that many threads. Even so, it doesn't do much concurrent processing because each `threads[i].join()` doesn't return until the that thread is finished. I suggest you use [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) to create a `Pool` of a reasonable fixed number of worker threads to process the files. You can then use things like `Pool.map()` to manage their execution.

Comment: @martineau okay, i'll try this now. But I don't understand why you say that the code creates 11 million threads? As I understand, here ```for i in range(num_threads):
        th = Thread(target = worker, args = (q, csv_writer_lock, writer))
        threads.append(th)``` I create ```num_threads = 4``` threads and then they process the filenames through the queue. Isn't that the same "fixed number of worker threads" in the ```Pool``` you've just mentioned?

Comment: Oops, sorry my mistake, I was thinking the loop was `for i in range(len(fnames))` — regardless, using a `Pool` would be an improvement because it will manage the threads for you and loops like that won't be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved after editing 
`json_text = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))` to

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    json_text = pickle.load(f)
```

and reloading python.
Thanks @martineau for the idea.

**UPD**
This is not the solution.

**UPD2**
Finally I think I figured out what was the problem. I run python on iMac with Fusion Drive. That's why the writing slows down at some moment.

Fusion Drive has 128 Gb SSD and the rest 2 Tb HDD. That means that MAC OS moved files in the beginning of a Queue, that I processed for testing the code(see `I checked 200, 2000, 20000, 50000, 100000 files to write.`), to SSD, because they were often used. That's why reading was so fast in the beggining, but later it slowed down, because reading started from HDD.

I checked the time to read `filename` and `writerow` in `worker` and approved that time to read `filename` significantly(about minimum 10-12x) increases after a while. Meanwhile waiting to release the `lock` and to `writerow` stays almost the same.

@martineau, I tried two ways to use Pool:

```
def worker_pool(csv_writer_lock, writer, filename):
    start = time.time()

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        json_text = pickle.load(f)

    with csv_writer_lock:
        if isinstance(json_text['Data']['Report'], dict):
            writer.writerow(json_text['Data']['Report'])
        elif isinstance(json_text['Data']['Report'], list):
            for report in json_text['Data']['Report']:
                writer.writerow(report)

    time_list.append(time.time() - start)

#%% by Pool
start = time.time()
time_list = []
csv_writer_lock = threading.Lock()
os.chdir('output')
with open('fulldb_ExtendedReport2.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    try:
        os.chdir('ExtendedReport')
        fieldnames = list(added_dict['Report'].keys())
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)

        writer.writeheader()

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 6) as pool:
            for filename in fnames:
                future = pool.submit(worker_pool, csv_writer_lock, writer, filename)

        os.chdir('..')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error')
        os.chdir('..')
print("Writing complete")
os.chdir('..')
end = time.time()

#%% by Pool2
start = time.time()
time_list = []
csv_writer_lock =  multiprocessing.dummy.Manager().Lock()
os.chdir('output')
with open('fulldb_ExtendedReport2.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    os.chdir('ExtendedReport')
    fieldnames = list(added_dict['Report'].keys())
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()

    pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(10)
    func = partial(worker_pool, csv_writer_lock, writer)
    pool.map(func, fnames)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    os.chdir('..')
print("Writing complete")
os.chdir('..')
end = time.time()
```

but both didn't increase speed, or even slowed down. Maybe I am doing something wrong... Appreciate if you give some comments.

Comment: I thought you said in a comment that this only postponed the problem. You also shouldn't put corrections into the code in your question because it makes it senseless.

Comment: @martineau Okay, sorry. Will know in the future. However actually, I made my code to write in file for a night, and the estimated time should be about 2 hours. However about 12 hours past and the program still writes and the speed slowed down again. I'll make updates of the code in the question bottom.